# Why do I have to rebuild the indexes on a table after inserting >150,000 records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, indexing

I have a daily process which imports about 150,000 records into two tables, and later joins them to compare against other data.

I have created indexes on the tables which makes the comparison process very fast.  Unfortunately, after the import process, the fragmentation on my indexes jumps way up, usually well over 50%.  I then have to rebuild the indexes before I can run my comparison query.

This doesn't make sense to me.  Shouldn't the index update itself appropriately when data is inserted?  Are there any properties on the index that would affect this behavior?

**edit:**
Some additional information--I have two tables.  During the import process, one table gets about 150,000 rows added to it via a insert/select statement.  The other table gets 150,000 rows from SQLBulkCopy at the application level.

Comment: How are you doing your inserts?

Comment: read about tree re-balancing, for example [here](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2012/07/03/computer-algorithms-balancing-a-binary-search-tree/), this will help you to understand why indexes should be re-built

Comment: Thanks @Lashane that makes sense--but is it possible to 'rebalance' the index as the items are inserted?

Comment: You can specify a [FILL FACTOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177459.aspx) for each of your indexes.  This can lessen the percentage of fragmentation and alleviate the need to REBUILD/REORGANIZE indexes as frequently as rows are added/updated.  Be aware-there are some trade-offs...

Comment: @SeanLange I updated the question to include by insert methods

Comment: @Slider345 it is possible, but it is heavy operation and takes time, so if full tree will be re-balanced after each insert - 150,000 rows will be inserted in several weeks, so it is trade off, just make it as habit: after each bulk table update - rebuild indexes and update statistics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But the index is updating itself properly.
Unless you are adding data exactly in the order of the index the index will fragment.

A few thing to consider:

- Can you insert the data in the order of the index?
  This will reduce fragmentation.
- Consider dropping the index, inserting the data, and then rebuilding the index.
  If you are getting 50% fragmentation then this will most likely be faster. 
  A fragmented index will slow down inserts.
- If you have to leave the index hot then consider a fill factor of 50%.
  This will slow down the rate of fragmentation with inserts significantly.